# J2SE simple event handling library

Tags: java, multithreading

Can you help me to find a simple event handler library - so that in some multi-threaded application I can just trigger an event (and attach some data to the event), and then some Pool of Threads will execute this event (if there is a subscriber).

I just need this inside the same JVM, so anything complex like JMS would be an overkill.

So basically I am looking for a simple event loop which works fine in Tomcat.

Comment: https://github.com/rfqu/df4j

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use Guava which, among other great things, has an [EventBus](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/EventBusExplained), and an [AsyncEventBus](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/eventbus/AsyncEventBus.html) allowing to deliver events asynchronously, using an executor.

Comment: Hi, this seems like what I need, thanks!